# Access Javascript Library D3 from GWT

Tags: gwt, d3.js

I include the d3 javascript like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.nocache.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then when I call it from the entry point d3 is null, why?

```
package com.example.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;


public class D3 implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        test();
    }
    private native void test()/*-{
        $wnd.alert($wnd.d3); 
     }-*/;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that the problem was that I named the project D3. Need to call it something else because it seems that it overwrites the D3 of the javascript library.